# Prayer in a chapel (bes midrash room) vs. in the main synagogue

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, architecture-design

Some synagogues have a room for prayers that's used on a regular basis: weekdays, *Shabasos*, holidays. If there are two simultaneous *minyanim*, then one will be elsewhere, of course, but otherwise the main prayer room is always used.

Other synagogues have a main prayer room used on *Shabasos*, holidays, and on certain other occasions; on weekdays, however, prayers are held in a smaller room, often called the "chapel" or the "*bes midrash*", and the large prayer room goes unused.

Obviously, acoustics, demographics, and other pragmatics might influence whether a given synagogue is of the first type (described in the first paragraph) or of the second (described in the second paragraph). I am wondering whether there are also *halachic* or philosophical issues that affect this choice: do, for example, synagogues of the first type follow one *halachic* ruling or moral teaching, and those of the second type follow another?

Comment: Often it is done out of practical, not philosophical considerations. Not to heat or air condition a large congregation when there are not that many people.

Comment: @GershonGold, yes, I mentioned as much in my question, which then went on to ask whether there are _halachic_ or philosophical considerations also.

Comment: The Fashion District shul in Manhattan is a nice example.  For Yom Tov they actually have a large sanctuary, but for weekday they get just barely a minyan, so they use the small bais medrash.  (7th and 40th st, north west corner).  Conservative too I think.

Comment: In my comment I noted that it is done out of practical, not philosophical considerations.

Comment: @GershonGold, ah, pardon me. I thought you were saying *often* it is out of practical considerations only (leaving room for other considerations on other occasions).

Comment: Some shuls hold that everyone should come to minyan everyday, others hold that most people are patur from minyan during the week.

Comment: @DoubleAA, is that a joke?  If not, a source please.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen I think it's a joke :)

Comment: There is a concern expressed in _B'rachos_ about davening in an open space, from which the _Aroch Hashulchan_ [90](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/ערוך_השולחן_אורח_חיים_צ#סימן_צ_סעיף_ח) extrapolates the principle that if one has a choice between two differently enclosed davening places one should choose the one less prone to distractions, which tends to be the more enclosed one. In some dichotomous room situations like the one described I've seen the smaller room be [near] more of an open/trafficked one, in which case this principle could influence the decision.