# Who was the strongest person in Tanach?

Tags: tanach, historical-figures

I found, lying in a local synagogue's [*bes midrash* room](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12641), a card that looks as though it came from a children's Judaism-trivia game. It had four questions on it, and, on the reverse side, their answers. One question was (if I recall the wording precisely):

> Who was the strongest person in the Bible?

The answer given was *Shimshon*.

He is, of course, described as strong ([*Shof'tim* 14](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0714)–16). But so are *B'nayahu* ([Ⅱ *Sh'muel* 23](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T08b23):20–23), *Aharon* ([*Bamidbar* 8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0408):11), and others. Do we have any tradition, or is there any evidence, as to who was strongest?

(I assume physical strength was meant by the game manufacturer: at any rate, that's what I'm referring to. Not, for example, strength of character.)

Comment: Pirkei Avot says that anyone who squelches his evil impulse is stronger than even the mightiest person.

Answer (score 10):

**Concerning Og**, see [Numbers Raba Hukat](http://www.tsel.org/torah/midrashraba/hukat.html) 32: *... that no strong one in the world arose that that was more fierce than he*, (קשה הימנו‏)*... And he remained from the mighty ones who were killed by Amrafel and his friends, ([Gen 14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0114.htm))... And he was a husk of them, like peels of olives in the olive waste.*

So from this saying, it would seem that **Og** was the strongest, and even he was put to shame by the mighty **Refaim** he hailed from.

**Another** instance can bee seen in [Tanhuma Mattos](http://www.tsel.org/torah/tanhuma/matot.html) 5: *Two strong ones arose in the world. Samson from Israel and Goliath from the nations of the world. And both of them were lost from the world, etc... Why? Because their gift was not from Gd, rather they seized it for themselves.*

Notice that the 'And' separates the two statements. In other words, the midrash is not saying that "there were two strong people who were lost from the world", It is saying "(1) There were two strong people in the world, AND (2) both of them were lost from the world."

It would seem that either **Samsom** or **Goliath** was the strongest person from this saying.

**To offer a resolution of these conflicting Midrashim**, perhaps *all* of the above mentioned were "the strongest" at one point in time. The *Refaim* were the strongest until they were killed in Abraham's time. Then *Og* took the title until Moses killed him. Then *Samson* was strongest, until he sacrificed himself to destroy the Philistines. Finally, *Goliath* was strongest until he was killed by David.

**In any event**, one can see that referring to someone as *"the strongest"* in rabbinic sayings is not meant in an absolute sense. Even if you reject my understanding of Samson and Goliath, you must accept the very plain inferiority given to Og as opposed to the Refaim, alongside Og's being called *"the strongest"*.

**I think that as far as finding an absolute winner goes, at best we have specific anecdotes to examine.**

Using the above premise, **Samson seems to be the winner thus far**. See [Sotah 9a](http://halakhah.com/sotah/sotah_9.html), where Rav Asi says that He uprooted the two great mountains, Tzorah and Eshta'ol and ground them together. Even Og only lifted one mountain, as seen on [Brachot 54b](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=brachos&daf=54b).

[Genesis Rabah Vayehi](http://www.tsel.org/torah/midrashraba/vayechi.html) 99:11, is also worth mentioning, though it may be less conclusive. It quotes Dan's blessing in [Genesis 49](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0149.htm):16, *...like one of the tribes of Israel, like the One of the world. Just as the One of the world needs no aid in war, so did Samson who arose from Dan need no others to help him, without a sword, rather with a donkey's jawbone*.

So Samson essentially founded the term 'one man army', requiring neither outside assistance, nor sufficient arms to defeat overwhelming odds.

Comment: ... Based on this is it really possible to definitively answer the question by finding an absolute winner? All that we have are anecdotes, detailing what people did, (not what they *could* do, in other words not their full capacity of strength), and titles of gibor, which are not absolute.

Comment: A _midrash_ that says explicitly that someone was the strongest person ever is what I was thinking of when I asked the question.

Comment: Right, I'm with you, but the midrash basically says those words by Og... Right before it says that he was a wimp compared to the Refaim. So I'm wondering if we can take any statement to this affect as absolute.

Comment: But Moshe defeated Og - doesn't that mean Moshe is stronger? Likewise, Dovid was stronger than Golias - doesn't that mean that Dovid is stronger?

Comment: I would throw Nimrod in the mix. The Torah says that he was "brave" and I think Midrashim also explain his physical strength.

Answer (score 6):

The gemarah in [sotah 10a](http://halakhah.com/sotah/sotah_10.html) describes Shimshon's strength as was in the likeness of God, so I would go with that.

Comment: Fair enough, if no one else is so described. D'you know?

Comment: @msh210 Even if someone else is, wouldn't they both be strongest?

Comment: @DoubleAA, maybe. Maybe strength _meen dugma shel maala_ is lesser than strength [insert some other unusual prepositional phrase here]. By "so described" I meant with that phrase or any similar.

Answer (score 2):

He fulfilled the verse in the torah "one of you will destroy 1000" (Joshua 23:10) when he slew 1000 plishtim in one battle

no one else in the tanach was able to do this.even the elite of David as mentioned in Shmuel II 23, only managed to reach 800 plishtim in one battle

Comment: Killing the most doesn't necessarily mean physically the strongest.

Comment: when the book of shmuel ii ch.23 lists the giborim of David it describes them by how many they killed

Comment: Yeah, I'm just saying that there are ways to kill, even ways to kill in battle, that don't rely specifically on high physical strength -- striking from behind, being part of a group (so it's N on 1), tripping, feinting -- none of that requires being able to bench-press 1000lbs or the like.

Comment: @MonicaCellio see gen rab 99:11, (details in my answer) that Samson did this alone and poorly armed. +1 from me, ray. Consider adding your remark about giborim determined by body count into the answer, that would make your point more clear i think.

Comment: Also just realized that 'He' is not identified in answer. You mean Samson right?

Comment: @BabySeal yes. thnx.

Comment: Dovid killed Golias alone and poorly armed.

Comment: @YEZ and moses killed Og - but that was one time miracles. unlike samson whose whole life ws like this

Comment: @ray also we know the way they killed them and it wasn't by way of strength. It was precision slinging by David and an impressive vertical jump by Moshe. It's not like they arm wrestled.

Comment: @ray MonicaCellio's point was that you don't have to be "strong" to kill.  If he had been breaking bones by flicking his pinkie you could bring a proof.  But he was using a weapon, and weapons can kill without strength.  Thus my proof from Dovid.  (I happen to agree that Shimshon did it through strength, but your proof is not a proof.)

Comment: @ray: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33189&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=, Judah killed 120k!

Comment: @YEZ a sling was a conventional weapon, unlike a donkey's jaw. I would consider a sling to be sufficient arms in the right hands.

Comment: @BabySeal What does convention have to do with it?  The question is if it is a lethal weapon.  They used to make swords out of bone, because they can be very solid weapons.  A ninja with a sword could kill a lot of people with skill, not strength.  Your mountain example is much better - that requires strength.